# ruby array strange thing (infinite array)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

When i write the following code:

```
x= [1,2,3]
x << x
puts x
puts x[3]
puts x[3][3][3][3][3][3][3][3][3][3]
```

I get this output:

```
[1, 2, 3, [...]]
[1, 2, 3, [...]]
[1, 2, 3, [...]]
```

Shouldn't I get only [1,2,3,[1,2,3]] and what would be the explanation?

Answer (score 10):

There's nothing strange about this. The fourth element of the array is the array itself, so when you ask for the fourth element, you get the array, and when you ask for the fourth element of the fourth element, you get the array, and when you ask for the fourth element of the fourth element of the fourth element of the fourth element ... you get the array.

Simple as that.

The only slightly unusual thing is that `Array#to_s` detects such recursion and instead of going into an infinite loop, returns an ellipsis.

Comment: In Ruby 1.9, `Array#<=>`, `#eql?` and `#hash` also deal with recursion, same for `Hash` and `Struct`...  Not sure why you consider it "unusual"! http://blog.marc-andre.ca/2009/05/lost-in-recursion.html

Comment: I don't think "infinitely recursive self-referential array" is a typical use case that the normal programmer would consider :-) I've written my share of `to_s` implementations, but I never considered special casing for *that*. If someone asks for a string representation of an infinite data structure, they'll get an infinite loop. Period. I mean, `map` for an infinite `Enumerator` returns an infinitely large array, and nobody thinks twice about that, isn't that somewhat the same?

Comment: I think it's nice that Ruby deals with recursive structures nicely. I'm not sure they are so unusual, e.g. structures that hold their parent & children. If that wasn't the case, ref counting would be all that's needed to handle memory :-)

Comment: Oh, another case where they're handled properly: YAML & Marshal dumps/loads.

Comment: I consider it unusual because i think i should have get [1,2,3,[1,2,3]]. Do you have other examples of this?

Answer (score 7):

When you write `x << x` you are appending to `x` with a reference to itself, creating a recursive/infinite array.

Compare this with `x << x.dup` which appends a copy of `x` onto `x`. This is equal to `[1,2,3,[1,2,3]]`

Comment: yes that's right, but shouldn't it be the same if I was writing `x+=x `? I mean to create an other kind of recursive array.

Comment: `x+=x` is equivalent to `x = x + x`, which means create a new array by joining the elements from `x` with the elements from `x` and then make `x` refer to this newly created array so you end up with `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]`. `<<` pushes the given object onto the end of an array (no new array is created.) See the [docs for +](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000271) and [docs for <<](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000225).